# Mark.js within chrome extension / further understanding

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

So I was attempting to strip down some mark.js example code and have come across some incredibly quirky behavior

The following code works as it looks (a simple HTML example then highlighted by a mark.js instanse)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<h> text in a header </h>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body context">
    <p>
    text ā text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
<p> text in a plain div </p>
</div>

<script src="mark.js"></script>
<script>
console.log("in our script");
var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("body"));
instance.mark("text", {
    "iframes": true,
});
</script>
```

Now when I remove the 'ā' (which is assumed to be nothing but another character within the

) it breaks the example and instances of 'text' are no longer highlighted

The bigger context of why I am attemping this is to use mark.js in a chrome extension, which I am able to get it in an extension (in content.js) and properly add "mark.js" to the manifest  such that the extension is able to create an instance, but I was not seeing it highlight on pages (like when this example is broken)

Any tips / insight as to what's going on here and how it may help my bigger goal of integrating mark.js into a chrome extension?

Thanks!